# MYSQL - Stored Procedure Utilising Comma Separated String As Variable Input

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Im hoping someone will be able to help. I have created my first stored procdure (nothing fancy) however im running into an issue.

I want to give it a string input such as 1,2,3,4,5 then it does a simple `SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE EAN IN (VAR);`

So the stored proc looks like this:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `moments`.`new_procedure`(IN var1 VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM moments.PRODUCT WHERE EAN IN (var1);

END
```

Im am trying to execute it like such:

**Works**

```
call moments.new_procedure('5045318357397')
```

**Does Not Work**

```
call moments.new_procedure('5045318357397,5045318357427');
```

This executes but doesnt not bring back any results. Is it classing the second statement as a string so its doing this:

```
select * from moments.PRODUCT WHERE EAN IN ('5045318357397,5045318357427')
```

and not this:

```
select * from moments.PRODUCT WHERE EAN IN ('5045318357397','5045318357427')
```

How do i have to format the input in the execute query to get it to take a comma separated string as an input?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT * FROM moments.PRODUCT 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(EAN, var1)
```

This should work assuming it is actually comma delimited. Any other delimiting will not work in this case.

Comment: This works perfectly inside the stored proc, thanks you. This is also how i will be calling it from Cast Iron application, which is an added bonus.

Comment: this works, but it is not very efficient as it needs to fetch all rows from the table then compare each row to your set, which in turn also has to loop through the comma separated list to check if it matches... If your # of columns is low, then it's fine otherwise you should find a batter way

Comment: @Populus comment needs to be uprooted more - FIND_IN_SET does not use any table indices, so is potentially a huge performance problem if used in this way

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the string you passed is validated somehow and doesn't contain malicious sql, you can use prepared statements :

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM CONCAT('select * from moments.PRODUCT WHERE EAN IN (',var1,')');
EXECUTE stmt1;
```