# How to Pass a List of String in MySQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to pass an array as a String in MySQL Stored Procedure but it doesn't work fine.

Here's my SQL Codes:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `search_equipment`(IN equip VARCHAR(100), IN category VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT *
        FROM Equipment
        WHERE e_description
        LIKE CONCAT("%",equip,"%")
            AND e_type IN (category)
END
```

And here's how i call the procedure:

```
String type = "'I.T. Equipment','Office Supply'";

CALL search_equipment('some equipment', type);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your friend here is FIND_IN_SET I expect.  I first came across that method in this question : also covered in this question [MYSQL - Stored Procedure Utilising Comma Separated String As Variable Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463001/mysql-stored-procedure-utilising-comma-separated-string-as-variable-input)

MySQL documention for FIND_IN_SET is here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

So your procedure will become

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `search_equipment`(
    IN equip VARCHAR(100), 
    IN category VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Equipment
    WHERE e_description LIKE CONCAT("%",equip,"%")
    AND FIND_IN_SET(e_type,category)
END
```

This relies on the category string being a comma-delimited list, and so your calling code becomes

```
String type = "I.T. Equipment,Office Supply";

CALL search_equipment('some equipment', type);
```

(p.s. fixed a typo, in your arguments you had typed categoy)

Comment: Not only `FIND_IN_SET` is my friend, today you are my friend too.

Answer (score 3):

you have to create a dynamic statment:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `search_equipment`(IN equip VARCHAR(100), IN category VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SET @s = 
        CONCAT('SELECT *
            FROM Equipment
            WHERE e_description
            LIKE \'%',equip,'%\'
            AND e_type IN (',category,')');
    PREPARE stmt from @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END$$
```

Comment: Simon at mso.net's SOlution is easier than mine, although probably not as fast. If your table is not huge (read millions of rows), the FIND_IN_SET solution is better.

Comment: This is the best answer I received.
Using FIND_IN_SET on my query lasted 48 seconds. Your (ugly) solution lasts 1.6 second.
Not sure why we can't pass lists to procedures. This make the code unclear to have to use CONCAT

Answer (score 1):

This helps for me to do IN condition
Hope this will help you..

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `test`(IN Array_String VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Table_Name
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(field_name_to_search, Array_String);

END//;
```

Calling:

```
call test('3,2,1');
```