# Python list of String to SQL IN parameter

Tags: python, mysql, list

I have this query in python:

```
ssim_group = [S1200,S1300]

query = '''select WIPMessageCnt from waferdata where recipename in (%s) and equipment = ?
                             and runtype = ? order by  stopts desc limit 1''' % (','.join(ssim_grp))
```

print query

Current result

> > select WIPMessageCnt from waferdata where recipename in (S1200,S1460) and equipment = ?
> >                                      and runtype = ? order by  stopts desc limit 1

Expected result should be like this

> > select WIPMessageCnt from waferdata where recipename in ('S1200','S1460') and equipment = ?
> >                                      and runtype = ? order by  stopts desc limit 1

The list should have single qoutation on each element when I try to put them inside the IN parameter on SQL. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Pass a List of String in MySQL Stored Procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103058/how-to-pass-a-list-of-string-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

Comment: `...WHERE FIND_IN_SET(recipename, %s) > 0...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ssim_group = ['S1200', 'S1300']
query = '''select WIPMessageCnt from waferdata where recipename in ('%s') and equipment = ? and runtype = ? order by  stopts desc limit 1''' % ("','".join(ssim_group))
```

Comment: this does not work if string has a quote like `['S1200', "S1300's"]`