# Python list of ints in prepared sql statement

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc, sqlanywhere

My question is somewhat the same as [Python list of String to SQL IN parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897802/python-list-of-string-to-sql-in-parameter) but I have a list of integers. The python code I use is:

```
ids = [1000032, 1000048]
sql = 'SELECT CompNo, CompName, CompType FROM Component WHERE DeptID IN (?)'    
cursor.execute(sql, [','.join(ids)])
```

And the Sybase database engine responds with:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('07006', "[07006] [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Cannot convert '1000032','1000048' to a numeric (-157) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO a more readable way to build a dynamic query string with placeholders using [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format)

```
ids = [1000032, 1000048]
sql = 'SELECT CompNo, CompName, CompType FROM Component WHERE DeptID IN ({0})' 
sql = sql.format(','.join('?' * len(ids)))
cursor.execute(sql, (ids,))
...
```

Comment: what is {0} for?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot provide the IN-list as one argument. You need to provide the exact number of place holders in the SQL IN clause, and then provide the array to the *execute* method:

```
ids = [1000032, 1000048]
sql = 'SELECT CompNo, CompName, CompType FROM Component WHERE DeptID IN (' \
       + (',?' * len(ids))[1:] + ')'
cursor.execute(sql, ids)
```

Answer (score 2):

with f-string:

```
ids = [1000032, 1000048]
sql = f'SELECT * FROM Component WHERE DeptID IN {*ids,}'
cursor.execute(sql)
```

result of sql:

```
'SELECT * FROM Component WHERE DeptID IN (1000032, 1000048)'
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the array only has one element. You get an extraneous comma in the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

The more simpler and clean way to do it

```
ids = [1000032, 1000048]
sql = 'SELECT CompNo, CompName, CompType FROM Component WHERE DeptID IN %(ids)s' % {"ids": tuple(ids)}
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like Abhishek and Jano's answers as the cleanest here, but they each leave a trailing comma if `ids` only has one element (e.g. `WHERE DeptID IN (1000032,)`), which throws an error when passed to SQL.

Here's how I like to approach this type of set up, which I use often:

```
base_sql = 'SELECT CompNo, CompName, CompType FROM Component'
where_clause = "" if IDs is None else f"where DeptID in ({','.join([str(x) for x in IDs])})"
final_sql = base_sql + where_clause
```

Below are the `final_sql` strings we get for different `IDs` lists/params:

```
IDs = None
> final_sql
'SELECT CompNo, CompName, CompType FROM Component'
```

,

```
IDs = [1,2]
> final_sql
'SELECT CompNo, CompName, CompType FROM Componentwhere DeptID in (1,2)'
```

and, crucially vs some other answers here, no trailing comma for single-ID lists:

```
IDs = [1]
> final_sql
'SELECT CompNo, CompName, CompType FROM Componentwhere DeptID in (1)'
```

Answer (score 0):

you should cast the array of int to array of strings:

```
",".join(map(str,ids))
```