# Python - Passing in product name in the where clause dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, where-clause, dynamically-generated

I have a Python dictionary that has list of all products we sell. Is is possible to have these products entered in a WHERE clause of a SQL statement as shown below and get the corresponding output.

**Dictionary**

Given below is the list of products we sell:

```
prod_list : [prod_a, prod_b, prod_c, prod_d]
```

I am looking to have a separate SQL generated for each of these products wherein the above mentioned prod_names would be used in the where clause in the SQL listed below:

**Sample SQL:**

```
select prod_id,prod_name,count (*)
from daily_sales
where prod_name = '' <-- this value to be pulled from the dictionary above
group by prod_id,prod_name
```

I am using Amazon Redshift DB..

Could anyone guide me on how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly needs to go in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Please post a valid python data structure as input. I see a list of dictionaries if anything.

Comment: @glibdud, trying to pass in prod_names in the where clause namely prod_a, prod_b, prod_c

Comment: @schwobaseggl, I basically have a list that has prod_name and prod_id as a dictionary. I could probably convert it into a dataframe. But would like to know how could I dynamically pass the prod_names into the where clause

Comment: I think a more complete example would be helpful. Are you trying to generate a query for one specific product? A list of products?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061730/python-list-of-ints-in-prepared-sql-statement

Comment: Also, what DB are you using?

Comment: @glibdud, I am trying to generate a query that would execute for each products in a loop.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it in my inital post. I am using Redshift DB..

Comment: @darkhorse It is not clear what clause you want to generate. `where prod_name = 'prod_a','prod_b','prod_c`' is not valid SQL. `where prod_name = 'prod_a,prod_b,prod_c`' will probably try to access an unexisting column

Comment: @Goyo, I basically have list of all product names stored seperately. I am trying to pass in these values into the SQL query in the where clause and extract the output..

Comment: @darkhorse I think you already said that, but it doesn't tell me what where clause you want.

Comment: if it was to it once, I could have added where prod_name = prod_a. I have a list of products and would like to do it in a loop for a list of products. I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: @ Oh, if by chance you want to generate and execute a separate SQL command for each product I think that is relevant and should be explained **in the question**.

Comment: My bad, if I did not convey my message correctly. Let me edit my question and add in these points so that it would help readers understand what I was looking for..

Comment: @Goyo, add few more points.. Hope this would make better sense of what  I am looking for..