# MYSQL - Stored Procedure to update column based on input parameter

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a simple question,

I have table:

```
| val | type | status |
|-----|------|--------|
|  90 |    1 |      a |
```

i would like to have a stored proc that able to update above table based on variable given in input param.

for example, maybe in PHP i have array:

```
$data = ['val' => 80, 'status' => 'c']
```

i would like to send that data to mysql stored proc, so it'll knows that it need to `update val to 80 and status into 'c'`

or another example:

```
$data = ['type' => 1, 'nothing' => NULL, 'status' => NULL, 'val' => 77]
```

then it will `update type to 1, status to null, val to 77 and ignore 'nothing'`

*the $data input, shall not hardcoded in input param in Stored Proc :D

is this can be done 'simply' ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use a stored proc instead of a simple UPDATE statement?

Comment: As @PaulSpiegel mentioned, what's stopping you from using an UPDATE statement?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, Do you mean like 'generating' dynamic update statement, then send it to mysql to execute? - well yeah, that maybe can be done, but maybe could lead me to another problem since it's not the only statement of the process (i have quite a few process before and after this update statement).
and it also make my standard different, since i put all of 'any related' db transaction in SP.
unless it really can't be done, then I will apply exception on this...

Comment: Maybe you should change your "standard".

Answer (score 1):

**Simple** answer than a stored procedure :

```
<?php

$data = ['val' => 80, 'status' => 'c'];

function auto($x){
$field_string ='';
$input_string='';
foreach  ($x as $userInfo=>$userInfo_value){
    if($userInfo_value !=''){
        echo $userInfo."->".$userInfo_value;
        if ($field_string == '') {
            $field_string = $field_string.$userInfo.' = '.$userInfo_value; 
        }
        else {
            $field_string = ','.$field_string.'='.$userInfo_value; 
        }
    }
}
$sql = "UPDATE protocole_test SET ".$field_string."WHERE (condition not specified in question) "; 
echo $sql ; //check query formed add a execution line after this

}

auto($data);
?>
```

**Explanation :**

Here we make a php function which handle your DATA ARRAY and form a dynamic update statement to update select fields with selected data.

**Why not stored procedures ?**

1) Stored procedures are stored in MYSQL engine

2) It cannot process DYNAMIC , VARIABLE LENGTH data arrays SIMPLY.

**Still how to do procedural style :**

Check out [Passing string to Mysql Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103058/how-to-pass-a-list-of-string-in-mysql-stored-procedure).

Algorythem :

1) form a quamma seprated list like -> key,value,key,value with help of php as used in above php answer;

2) Call Procedure with QCM as parameter ;

3) Edit procedure to update fields (in answer insert operation is performed);

4)test.

**Advantage of using php function :**

1) Its simple .
2) it satify all purpouse of making a STORED PROCEDURE.
3) Its can also be  called by ajax.

Thank you very much.